# How to update records from popup form in laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

**Buttons in navbar.blade.php file**
   Each time when user click on edit button then its correspondence ID should be pass through the this Form...
[image]

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Edit</button>
```

and this button is redirected to this form

```
 <form action="-----------" method="POST" role="form" class="form-horizontal">
 {{ csrf_field() }}
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="email" class="col-sm-2 control-label">
        Nav ID</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nav_id" placeholder="nav id" readonly="" />
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="email" class="col-sm-2 control-label">
        Nav Name</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nav_name" placeholder="nav name" />
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputPassword1" class="col-sm-2 control-label">
        Nav Details</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nav_description" placeholder="nav details" />
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-2">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">
            Submit</button>

   </div>
</div>
</form>
```

**So how to update the record of selected ID from .blade file and what should i write here in navbarController.php and in its route file**

```
 public function edit(Request $request) { 

   }
}
```

Comment: did you read the laravel documentation??

Comment: stackoverflow is not avaialble for free code where you get problem tell us

Answer (score 1):

It's the solution

add "edit-button" class to your button and using alt attribute to keep $ID

```
<button class="edit-button btn btn-primary" alt="<?=$ID?>" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Edit</button>
```

add hidden field to keep $ID to your form

```
<input id="id" type="hidden" name="id" value=""/>
```

Using @section and @yield to write jquery code to adjust value for hidden fields when the user click on edit button. let's see https://laravel.io/forum/09-02-2014-using-section-and-yield

```
@section('javascript')
 $("body").on('click','.edit-button',function(){
    var activeEditId = $(this).attr('alt');
    $("#id").val(activeEditId);
 )});
@stop
```